# Auto increment next number PHP

Tags: php, auto-increment

Can someone please help me. I need to get the next auto incremented number from a certain table.

```
            <th class="width1">
                <?php echo _l('Job Number:'); ?>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="job_name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($job['name']); ?>" />
```

;

```
            </td>
```

where would and what would I add to this to achieve what I want. I have tried a few things but its driving me crazy.

Any help appreciated thanks.

Ash

Comment: Why do you need to know what the next value will be? And the answer is that you can't, not without creating a record and getting the id value that's assigned to that record

Comment: There are previous records. These are "Job Numbers" 
I want to be able to open the form and the next number already be there without manual imput. on my SQL database there is already a table with previous numbers.

Comment: You must be able to guarantee that another user running at the same time won't get the same job number.... you can't do that without actually incrementing the autoincrement value

Comment: There will never be a scenario where 2 of the technicians will be pressing the save button or creating a job sheet at the same time so that's not really an issue.

Comment: `There will never be a scenario` - how many times have I heard that before

Comment: or if you think you know a solution to this so 2 users could do it at the same time. please share

Comment: Will the technician always save after filling in the data, or will they ever abort?

Comment: I told you the solution in my earlier comment.... you save a stub entry first, and get the autoincrement value from that

Comment: Okay I'm not familiar with how to do this. could you provide the code I'd need?

Comment: Create a new empty record, get the autoincrement value, that's the number you want to show as the job number; then when the technician has filled in the details, you update that record with those values

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'table'
AND table_schema = DATABASE()
```

You can run this query to find out the next auto increment of a table

Comment: Thats great thank you but where abouts in my code would I put the query?

Comment: Does this code actually increment the autoincrement value so that two users can run it concurrently an not get the same number?

Comment: @MarkBaker Nope, this would only get the next autoincrement of a table, it won't put other concurrent users into account. I don't think there's a way to do that.. or at least a reliable way to do that.

Comment: There will never be a scenario where 2 of the technicians will be pressing the save button or creating a job sheet at the same time so that's not really an issue.